# Problem adapting curl CLI cmd to php curl

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I am trying to use the 1fichier.com API to upload my files to the cloud
and I get this problem, it works fine on CLI but not with php curl.

CLI command:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer RxhbOxH0HmKHB0FEZsyW9OL_qky4UiOT" -v -F "file[]=@x.zip;filename=a355553.rar" https://up2.1fichier.com/upload.cgi?id=IBC8BTLJbP
```

CURL PHP:

```
function One_upload($file){
  $ids = One_url();
  $file_name_with_full_path ='C:\wamp64\www\pages\x.zip';
  $post = array('files[]'=>'@'.$file_name_with_full_path, 'filename' => 'sasa.zip');
  var_dump($post);

    $url = 'https://'.$ids['url'].'/upload.cgi?id='.$ids['id'];
    $headers = array(
    'Authorization: Bearer RxhbOxH0HmKHB0FEZsyW9OL_qky4UiOT',
    'Content-Length: '.filesize("x.zip"),
);
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close ($curl);
  return $response;

}
```

Comment: Specify what is "do not work". It throws some error?

Comment: Your `filename` parameter should be part of the `file[]` form field. You need to concatenate it instead of adding it as a separate array element